# How can we find all the posts of a deleted user from its user id?

Tags: support

If I know the user id of a deleted user for example 1224441, how can I find all the posts created by the user?

`user:1224441` in search box doesn't work.

The only way I know is google with `user1224441 site:stackoverflow.com`.
Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt you can. Posts from deleted users usually are deleted too (unless the user is impactful enough to keep them), deleted posts don't show up in search, and deleted posts in SEDE's PostsWithDeleted table are anonymized. You can, however, download old data dumps and analyze those, I think.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth They're only deleted if they have a negative score.  Otherwise they're just anonymized.

Comment: Ah, yes, interesting. In SEDE, they keep the user name, but remove the ID (at least, some of the really old ones I'm looking at). Do you have the name from that user?

Comment: @Erik Thanks. "ethan". Can you post the commands that you use to get and look up in SEDE?

Comment: @Tim Here is a [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866217/select-all-posts-from-deleted-user) to my SEDE query. Just enter the name.

Comment: @Erik: Thanks. But different user ids may have the same username. user id is the only way to identify a user.

Comment: True. I only get 3 hits on ethan all lowercase though, so it's not that many. Afaik (but I might be wrong there again) there's no way to differentiate posts by deleted users with the same name. If there are results by users thar aren't deleted, however, you can filter those out by adding `AND OwnerId Is Null` to that query.

Comment: Those you found are not from the user id. @Erik

Comment: @Erik I made a mistake the usrename is Ethan, not ethan. Still your query doesn't find any post from the user.

Comment: Hmm... That's strange. That column should be filled in if the `OwnerUserID` column is Null. Apparently, there are some weird posts where they're both Null, and those look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1692781/7296893) on Stack Overflow. Those aren't identifiable to a user at all, and I don't believe dissociated posts look like that either, they usually get a userSomeNumber slapped on there. Anyway, I'm at a loss then. Perhaps another user can help you.

Comment: Might [these](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866217/select-all-posts-from-deleted-user?DeletedUserUsername=user1224441) be the posts you're looking for? Apparently, since pretty long, the username gets changed to user<userID> when a user gets deleted.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes. Thanks. Still those deleted posts are not found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moderators have the ability to query for all posts by a deleted user, but that's a fairly new capability and not publicly exposed to regular users.

However, [Erik's query above](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866217/select-all-posts-from-deleted-user?DeletedUserUsername=user1224441) does seem to return publicly visible posts by that former user. The user actually had 44 posts, but 11 of them were negatively scored and removed upon their deletion. That leaves the 33 that his query returns.

Even for active users, deleted posts aren't listed in a profile unless a moderator is viewing it, so you'll have a harder time tracking down all deleted posts for a user without moderator or employee assistance.